# ipywidgets: minimizing button width to just show icon?

Tags: ipywidgets

I have a `VBox` of `HBox` instances, each `HBox` containing a `Text` and a `Button` instance:

[image]

Here is the code is the code I used:

```
        style = {'description_width': '125px', 'width': '90%'}
        for rest_id, prompt_text in fields.items():
            self.widgets[rest_id] = ipy.Text(
                    description=prompt_text,
                    disabled=False,
                    layout = ipy.Layout(width='99%'),
                    style=style)
            self.widgets[f"{rest_id}_button"] = ipy.Button(icon='cloud-upload')
            vbox_widgets.append(ipy.HBox(children=[self.widgets[rest_id], self.widgets[f"{rest_id}_button"]]))   
        self.widgets['meta_vbox'] = ipy.VBox(children=vbox_widgets)
```

Is there a way to fix the percentage of how much each item in an `HBox` gets?  Or to fix an `HBox` element to a fixed pixel count?  I want the `Button` instances to be just big enough to display the icon and nothing more.

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify a particular width (or a dedicated `Layout`) for your button, then the remaining objects should adjust to fill the space, does this give what you want?:

```py
import ipywidgets as ipy
fields = {'a': '1', 'b': '2'}
widgets = {}
vbox_widgets = []
style = {'description_width': '125px', 'width': '90%'}
button_layout = ipy.Layout(width='40px')
for rest_id, prompt_text in fields.items():
    widgets[rest_id] = ipy.Text(
            description=prompt_text,
            disabled=False,
            layout = ipy.Layout(width='99%'),
            style=style)
    widgets[f"{rest_id}_button"] = ipy.Button(icon='cloud-upload', layout=button_layout)
    vbox_widgets.append(ipy.HBox(children=[widgets[rest_id], widgets[f"{rest_id}_button"]]))   
ipy.VBox(children=vbox_widgets, layout=ipy.Layout(width='400px'))
```

[image]

For more complex layouts look at the GridBox class: https://ipywidgets.readthedocs.io/en/latest/examples/Widget%20Styling.html#The-Grid-layout

For future questions, it's a lot easier if you include all your imports, mock out the dictionary etc. Much easier to give a response if I can just copy and paste your code and run it.

Comment: Thanks @ac24!  I swear i had tried this before but I must have had something wrong in my style attributes.